# VS code javascript outline/table of contents

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to use the Outline tab in VS code to display a ToC of the current javascript document based on some tag used to indicate sections and subsections?

I am looking for something similar to [Creating Table of Contents in VS code Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67976088/creating-table-of-contents-in-vs-code-jupyter-notebook) or https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown (Outline view) but for javascript code.